# Запрос в таблицу базу данных (SQL), раздробление поля с большим значением, для получения новой таблицы

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, запрос, request

Есть **поле** в некой таблице SQL (**СУБД : Windows 10 Pro (10.0) Версия : 14.0.2027.2** запрос пишу на Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)

условно выглядит так (**поле типа Varchar**) //2-3 записей достаточно(комментарий @Akina), **ниже данные из одного поля**

```
ПолеМногогранное
ключ1 : значение1 / ключ2 : значение2 / ключ3 : значение3
ключ1 : значение4 / ключ2 : значение5 / ключ3 : значение6
ключ1 : значение7 / ключ2 : значение8 / ключ3 : значение9
```

На выходе необходима новая таблица с полями-ключ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос :** Какой запрос **SELECT** (ne Insert, ni Create, ni Delete..., потому что данные просто НАДО ИЗВЛЕЧЬ. Добавила эту строчку, потому что второй ответ уже с Insert) я могу реализовать, есть ли возможность детектировать некий ключ(?назовем условно ключ, но это повторюсь пользователь просто вводит вручную "что-то,двоеточие,слеш"), значение, и разделители в одном поле. То есть пользователь заполняет сам, не автоматизированно (*опускаю вопрос, опечатки, отсутствие неких ключей, забыли поставить разделитель, пока не важно*) (Пока условно нужно отталкиваться, как если бы пользователь ввел все правильно...)

**Просто что то вроде :**

```
select
    
    t.ПолеМногогранное(и тут наверно что то мне незнакомое по умолчанию) as Ключ1, 
    t.ПолеМногогранное(а если нет, то КАК) as Ключ2, 
    t.ПолеМногогранное(выбрать часть из общей информации поля) as Ключ3
    
from ТаблицаНекая t
```

@Yitzhak Khabinsky вот результат **SELECT TOP(10) ID, columnInQuestion FROM tableName;** первый запрос просто выход из таблицы, а второй  я добавила парамметр, и как видно по ID, данные есть, но далеко. и не всегда регулярные. Но главное, что в ответах у тех, кого БД более менее с корректными данными, ответы подойдут наверняка

```
**ID    columnInQuestion**
21      Ключ1 : Значение1 / Ключ2 : Значение2 Ключ3 : Значение3
784     Ключ1 : Значение 546546546g
785     Ключ1 : Значение dfdfde
786     Ключ1 : Значение AM 37081015.3
787     Ключ1: 7051 AM 22081027.4
1588    Ключ3 : Значение :значение
1589    Ключ3 : значение : ЗНАЧЕНИЕ
1590    Ключ3 : значение : ЗНАЧЕНИЕ
3720    КЛЮЧ1: ЗНАЧЕНИЕ
3721    КЛЮЧ1:  ЗНАЧЕНИЕ

**ID    columnInQuestion**
122525  Ключ1 : значение8 / Ключ2 / Значение9 / Ключ3 : Значение10
129978  Ключ1 : значение1 / Ключ2 / Значение2 / Ключ3 : Значение3 Ключ4 : Значение4
130028  Ключ1 : значение5 / Ключ2 / Значение6 / Ключ3 : Значение7
```

Всем спасибо, решение для моего случая ищу на стороне C#

Comment: Не надо вот этих "условно". Показывайте настоящую структуру (как CREATE TABLE скрипт), пример данных (как INSERT INTO скрипт), и требуемый вывод для именно этих данных (как форматированная таблица). И указывайте точно СУБД, включая её точную версию.

Comment: Create и Insert я к ним доступа не имею(и в данном случае не могу сказать как именно были введены данные в таблицу, при том, что база данных довольно старая‍♀️), моя задача реализовать верный Select. или я не поняла Вашего комментария ‍♀️

Comment: То есть Вы не знаете ни структуры таблицы, ни вида данных, ни даже какая там СУБД - а запрос всё же хотите создать? Вот прям сказки - поди туда не знаю куда.

Comment: @Akina
1. структура таблицы - в данном случае более подробно объясните пожалуйста
2. Вид данных, иммется ввиду их тип или ?
3. СУБД - MSSQLServer (?)
и потом разве это имеет значение к простому Select, тип поля просто Varchar

Comment: я же не хочу "создать что то", а уже из готового поля "извлечь бы" 

Comment: 1. Нужен точный тип данных поля с данными как минимум. 2. Пример данных - 2-3 записей достаточно. И именно для них нужно показать точный конечный результат. 3. Да, имеет, и очень важное. У каждой СУБД и даже у каждой версии свой набор средств работы с данными, свои операторы, функции и пр. Скажем, я сейчас напишу запрос для MySQL 8.0.22 - и хрен вы его на SQL server заставите работать...

Comment: Я же указала пример поля, выше в вопросе...(пометила рядом Ваше имя)
Тип просто строка...пользователь просто вводит, то ли через мобильное приложение то ли через веб сайт...как хочет так и вводит, всякий по разному

Comment: и вопрос в том, есть ли в языке sql что то, что позволит "условно" определить ключ, но это не ключ, это лишь слово, которое всегда одинаково для пользователя, и он вводит например ключ1ставит двоеточие и его значение, потом по идее ставит слеш и продолжает, и мне бы хотелось создать таблицу из одного поля, которое содержит набор...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115393/discussion-between-dev18-and-akina).

Comment: Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваши данные очень похожи на формат Json. Вот решение на основе SQL Server 2016 и более поздних версий.

То, что я вам предоставил, называется "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

(1) Вы можете скопировать его в SSMS, и он должен работать на вашем компьютере в вашей среде.

Раздел «DDL and sample data population» предназначен только для имитации вашей среды, потому что у меня нет вашей база данных (СУБД).

(2) Чтобы сработалo в вашей реальной среде, вам нужно внести несколько небольших изменений в предоставленный T-SQL:

- Игнорируйте DDL, который больше не нужен, и сосредоточьтесь на
  операторах CTE и `SELECT`.
- Замените **@tbl** своим настоящим именем таблицы. Замените **val** своим
  настоящим именем столбца.

**SQL #1, на основе Json**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, val NVARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(N'ключ1 : значение1 / ключ2 : значение2 / ключ3 : значение3'),
(N'ключ1 : значение4 / ключ2 : значение5 / ключ3 : значение6'),
(N'ключ1 : значение7 / ключ2 : значение8 / ключ3 : значение9');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(3) = ' / '
    , @separatorJson CHAR(3) = '","'
    , @colon CHAR(3) = ' : '
    , @colonJson CHAR(3) = '":"';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT ID
      , N'{"' + 
         REPLACE(REPLACE(val,@colon, @colonJson), @separator, @separatorJson) + 
            N'"}' AS DataJson
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID
    , JSON_VALUE(DataJson, N'$."ключ1"') AS [ключ1]
    , JSON_VALUE(DataJson, N'$."ключ2"') AS [ключ2]
    , JSON_VALUE(DataJson, N'$."ключ3"') AS [ключ3]
FROM rs;
```

**Результат**

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id |   ключ1   |   ключ2   |   ключ3   |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | значение1 | значение2 | значение3 |
|  2 | значение4 | значение5 | значение6 |
|  3 | значение7 | значение8 | значение9 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

**SQL #2, на основе XML**

```
;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT id
          , TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
                REPLACE(val, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
                ']]></r></root>' AS XML) AS xmldata
    FROM @tbl
), cte AS
(
    SELECT id
        , c.value('(r[1]/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS col1
        , c.value('(r[2]/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS col2
        , c.value('(r[3]/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS col3
    FROM rs CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/root') AS t(c)
)
SELECT id 
    , STUFF(col1, 1, CHARINDEX(@colon, col1,1) + 2, '') AS [ключ1]
    , STUFF(col2, 1, CHARINDEX(@colon, col2,1) + 2, '') AS [ключ2]
    , STUFF(col3, 1, CHARINDEX(@colon, col3,1) + 2, '') AS [ключ3]
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Данные это просто строка в формате Varchar. Вчера я долго мучалась, но так и не нашла как можно раздробить эту строку. Вы в своем ответе создаете таблицу, а в моем случае она УЖЕ СОЗДАННА и клиент хочет упорно работать с этой старой базой данных и я искала Select.

Comment: @Dev18 Э... таблица же тут создаётся исключительно в демонстрационных целях, Вы ведь не показали DDL своей реальной таблицы, а SELECT из чего-то делать надо...

Comment: @Dev18, Я обновил ответ с пояснениями.

Comment: ;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT ID
      , N'{"data": [{"' +    // что такое Select ID и что такое N (в данном запросе)

Comment: @Dev18, (1) Если в вашей реальной таблице нет столбца идентификаторов **ID**, вы можете удалить его. (2) N '...' означает тип данных NVARCHAR (), позволяющий использовать буквы русского языка.

Comment: есть id, но т.к. Вы написали id вначале с маленькой буквы, а потом с большой не была уверенна, что этом именно столбец идентификатора.

Comment: @Dev18, Обычно SQL Server к этому нечувствителен, поэтому нет разницы между **ID** и **id**.

Comment: в моем случае не сработало данное решение, но в любом случае кому то да поможет✔

Comment: @Dev18, (1) Пожалуйста, предоставьте дополнительную информацию, что не работает.(2) Мне нужен точный образец ваших данных. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте исходный пост и предоставьте это.

Comment: @Dev18, Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее **версия**? `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: @Dev18, Я обновил ответ с помощью решения на основе XML.

Comment: СУБД : Windows 10 Pro (10.0)
Версия : 14.0.2027.2

Comment: @Dev18, Итак, у вас есть SQL Server 2017. Решения на основе (1) Json и (2) XML должны работать для вас. (1) Пожалуйста, предоставьте дополнительную информацию, что не работает.(2) Мне нужен точный образец ваших данных. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте исходный пост и предоставьте это.

Comment: The format of the JSON text is not correct. An unexpected character “. Is in position 9.
// Видимо строка ===> JSON_VALUE(DataJson, N'$."ключ1"') AS [ключ1] то есть СОВПАДЕНИЕ со строкой "ключ" не находит ‍♀️, мне думается, что потому что как я и упомянула ранее строка не всегда содержит слово "ключ1", а например иногда просто пробел или "ключЬ", все дело в самой строке, которую они сохраняют и именно поэтому я сейчас работаю на стороне C#, потому что не могу визуализировать на стороне SQL мою таблицу. Вам огромное = Благодарю, и дай Бог, побольше в Нашем сообществе ВАС //ps вопрос UP+СУБД

Comment: @Dev18, Поделитесь, пожалуйста, результатом следующего T-SQL: `SELECT TOP(10) ID, columnInQuestion FROM tableName;`

Comment: я добавила в вопрос топ10, наверно надо удалить вопрос, потому что я отталкивалась от принципа, что там ключ:значение/ключ:значение/... а там даже не так как Вы видите, и в моем случае это дохлый вариант сложить что то и создать новую таблицу .  Поэтому сижу ломаю голову в C# и там полегче будет, но пока только вначале пути

Comment: @Dev18, Мы приближаемся к ответу... Поделитесь, пожалуйста, результатом следующего T-SQL: `SELECT TOP(10) ID, columnInQuestion FROM tableName WHERE CHARINDEX(':', columnInQuestion, 1) > 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Ну например

```sql
WITH cte AS (
SELECT test.id, 
       TRIM(SUBSTRING(splitted.value, 1, CHARINDEX(':', splitted.value) - 1)) [key], 
       TRIM(SUBSTRING(splitted.value, 1 + CHARINDEX(':', splitted.value), LEN(splitted.value))) value 
FROM test 
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(test.val, '/') AS splitted
)
SELECT id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN [key] = N'ключ1' THEN value END) [ключ1], 
       MAX(CASE WHEN [key] = N'ключ2' THEN value END) [ключ2], 
       MAX(CASE WHEN [key] = N'ключ3' THEN value END) [ключ3]
FROM cte
GROUP BY id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b2b93b1287b1a2cd2668ad977c66b672)

Comment: прикольный инструмент, что вы использовали (сохранила), и поняла, что легче просто поле извлечь и уже в C# создать словарь(ключ:значение"условно, потому что это не совсем ключ ведь"), и уже там продолжить извлекать данное значение поля и распределять по необходимым колонкам, так ка финальная стадия моей работы это конверт файл CSV, но это уже другой этап. Вначале просто хотела дать запрос и посмотреть на "сырую" таблицу в SQL формате. Но видимому такое по умолчанию не имеется...

Comment: если бы еще этот инструмент конвертировал запрос в нужной системе эксплуатации 

Comment: @Dev18 *такое по умолчанию не имеется* По умолчанию денормализованные данные вообще моветон. *прикольный инструмент* Да их как грязи... но этот мне нравится больше остальных.

Comment: эх, если бы пользователь понимал моветон‍(а ведь клиент всегда прав, и наша задача из "какашки" дать пользователю "цацу" ), так это приятно узнавать разные плюшки, которые помогают легче и красивей решение предложить // говоря пользователь, не могу сказать архитектор, тк. в до 90х они делали как могли...а база повторюсь старая, и там правда ужастик

Comment: @Dev18 А пользователь-то при чём? это архитектор, который верстал структуру БД, наваял такой ужастик. Уж лучше бы JSON-объекты сохранял - для них хоть какие-то инструменты имеются.